# Get the row number of query result in OrientDB

Tags: sql, orientdb, row-number

I am querying an OrientDB database, that has a `users` table, to get the current highscore.

Therefore, I need to know the index / row number for each of the returned rows. I am using a JS based wrapper for the DB interface, where the code currently looks like:

```
... .find('Users', {
    fields: 'username, points, row_number() AS ranking' 
    orderBy: 'points DESC,
});
```

... I have found `row_number()`  in some threads, but it doesn't seem to exist. What else could I use to get the ranking here?

Answer (score 0):

A Record (Document) is uniquely identified by OrientDB by its record id (or `rid`), see [documentation](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Concepts)

Comment: I do not need the identifier of the row in the database, but the number of the row in the sorted query result. The users' rankings will change over time, and so will hopefully their ranking, which I am trying to determine.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**. Starting from OrientDB 2.0.3-SNAPSHOT you can do:

```
.find('Users', {
  fields: '@rid, username, points, $counter AS ranking',
  let: '$counter = eval("$counter + 1")'
  orderBy: 'points DESC'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, please have a look at my comment on @rmuller's response: I do not need the identifier of the row in the database, but the number of the row in the sorted query result. The users' rankings will change over time, and so will hopefully their ranking, which I am trying to determine.